# What does this profiling result mean?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, optimization, profiling

I opened a project (Visual C# - Windows Forms) and profiled it, and got the "hottest" methods. Now I can't understand the results because the hottest method is "collapsed methods without source". How can i understand what to fix if I can't see the method? What should i do?

Here is a pic so you can understand. [image]

Comment: Did you try changing the display option to "show all methods"?

Comment: @RossFabricant how do i do this? do you mean this:  http://i54.tinypic.com/351izio.jpg  Edit:sorry i got this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the screen carefully, you'll notice the following:

> Collapsed methods without source. To view these methods, change the display option to show all methods.

So, try changing the display option to show all methods. That should fix your problem.

Once you know the methods, you'll need to go find them in your source code.